# How to redo a play in skill play

Tags: madden-21

I'm new to madden so I'm using the Skill Play to figure out the moves in Madden 21.  When you do a play and fail it, it just moves on to the next one.  This normally is not too big a problem, but I am currently working on ball carrier moves, which teaches a new move each play, so it's crucial that I am able to retry a specific play until I get it right.  The restart button restarts the whole tutorial, I only want to restart the particular play I'm on.  Is there a way to do this?